# resizing and centering a fixed position div with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, centering

I have a fixed position div with a fixed height/width.

The div is positioned using

position: fixed;

left = 50%;
margin-left = -(width/2)
top = 50%;
margin-top: = -(width/2)

The div has a black background.

What I want to do is, when a button is pressed calculate the size of the new contents (hidden dom element)

Fade the **contents** of the div out, animate it resizing to the new contents size (staying centered).

Fade the new contents in.

What is the easiest way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: i gave one more solution...try that it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this one also

```
this=$('#yourDiv');

    this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
```

This is from one of my applications , try and it should center it

refactor if you need any customization.

```
function centerPopup() {

    var windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $('#popupplaceholder').height();
    var popupWidth = $('#popupplaceholder').width();
        if (popupWidth > windowWidth) {
        popupWidth = (windowWidth) * (0.9);
    }
    if (popupHeight > windowHeight) {
        popupHeight = (windowHeight) * (0.9);
    }
    //centering
    var objControl = document.getElementById("yourDIV");
    if (objControl != null) {
        if (objControl.offsetParent != null) {
            var left = (objControl.offsetParent.clientWidth / 2) - (objControl.clientWidth / 2) + objControl.offsetParent.scrollLeft;
            var top = (objControl.offsetParent.clientHeight / 2) - (objControl.clientHeight / 2) + objControl.offsetParent.scrollTop;
            $('#yourDIV').css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": top,
                "left": left
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/EpzDM/

It works, but I don't doubt the JavaScript could be improved.

**JavaScript:**

```
var $box = $('#box');
var $boxInner = $box.find(' > div');

var fixIt = function() {
    var newWidth = 300;
    var newHeight = 150;

    $boxInner.fadeOut(function() {
        $box.animate({
            marginLeft: -newWidth/2,
            marginTop: -newHeight/2,
            width: newWidth,
            height: newHeight
        }, 500, function() {
            $boxInner.fadeIn();
        });
    });
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    $box.css({
        marginLeft: -$box.width()/2,
        marginTop: -$box.height()/2
    });
}).resize();

$('<button>Clicky!</button>').appendTo(document.body).click(fixIt).css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
        <p>Contents of div</p>
        <p>Contents of div</p>
        <p>Contents of div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```